# Filtering objects from array lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an Array like this

```
var data = [
 {attribute_code: "description", value: "<p>Description</p>"}, 
 {attribute_code: "category_ids", value: Array(2)},
 {attribute_code: "required_options", value: "0"},
 {attribute_code: "has_options", value: "0"},
 {attribute_code: "activity", value: "11,18,19,20,21,22,23"},
 {attribute_code: "material", value: "37,38"}
]
```

Using lodash i would like to remove `description, category_ids, required_options, has_options` from it to look like

```
[
 {attribute_code: "activity", value: "11,18,19,20,21,22,23"},
 {attribute_code: "material", value: "37,38"}
]
```

I tried something like this

```
const filter = _(customAttributes)
    .keyBy('attribute_code')
    .pullAt(['description', 'category_ids', 'required_options', 'has_options'])
    .value();
```

But this is returning

```
[
 {attribute_code: "description", value: "<p>Description</p>"}, 
 {attribute_code: "category_ids", value: Array(2)},
 {attribute_code: "required_options", value: "0"},
 {attribute_code: "has_options", value: "0"},
]
```

as _.at, i guess its not mutating the array. What am i doing wrong here? I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your original array is stored in `data`,

```
var data = [
 {attribute_code: "description", value: "<p>Description</p>"}, 
 {attribute_code: "category_ids", value: Array(2)},
 {attribute_code: "required_options", value: "0"},
 {attribute_code: "has_options", value: "0"},
 {attribute_code: "activity", value: "11,18,19,20,21,22,23"},
 {attribute_code: "material", value: "37,38"}
]
```

You can filter out unwanted elements with `filter` function:

```
var toRemove = new Set([
     "description",
     "category_ids",
     "required_options",
     "has_options"
])

_(data).filter(e => !toRemove.has(e.attribute_code)).value()
```

Also, this can be done without lodash.

```
data.filter(e => !toRemove.has(e.attribute_code))
```

Comment: That works. I get confused with all the methods and don't know which one to use at the end ty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dropWhile()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#dropWhile)

```js
var data = [{attribute_code: "description", value: "<p>Description</p>"},{attribute_code: "category_ids", value: Array(2)},{attribute_code: "required_options", value: "0"},{attribute_code: "has_options", value: "0"},{attribute_code: "activity", value: "11,18,19,20,21,22,23"},{attribute_code: "material", value: "37,38"}],
    removeParameters = ['description', 'category_ids', 'required_options', 'has_options'],
    result = _.dropWhile(data, ({attribute_code}) => removeParameters.includes(attribute_code));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh nice... always like to see different ways. Thank you